# Why do I have to type in my Apple ID password over and over again for free apps or reviews in App Store when I have a touch ID?

Tags: ipad, icloud, apple-id, password, touch-id

I'm just curious about something. So I have my iPad with a touch ID and I thought I set it up not to ask me for my Apple ID password in the settings:

[image]

So today I was trying to write a review for an app in the App Store:

[image]

and what do you know, it wants my Apple ID password and the fingerprint reader does not work for it.

Am I not setting something right? I thought the whole premise of selling us this touch ID thing is so that we won't have to type our passwords ever again. What am I missing here?

PS. For whoever wants to know what's so difficult about typing in my Apple password, I'd tell you that since not so long ago, after Apple had the "[Fappening](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICloud_leaks_of_celebrity_photos)" breach of celebrity pictures over iCloud, I changed my password to something like this "ih1!G832R5a1t2WlDLxt*eeFV" to prevent it from happening to my account. So as you can imagine, it's not easy to type it at a whim... especially for something as trivial as leaving an app review.

Comment: Your question title/header indicates that this occurs when you try to download free apps, but there is no mention of that in the body. Is that the case?

Comment: @jer-el: No. It's not.

Answer (score 1):

[All indications](https://support.apple.com/en-ca/HT201371) are that Touch ID can only be used for purchases. The grey message below the toggle in Settings indicates that as well.

You may not have much choice but to remember and type your password when writing reviews.